# How can I integrate VLC in angular?

Tags: angular, vlc, rtsp

Let's see if you can give me a hand.

I have an IP camera that serves images to a VLC player using the RTSP protocol. Now I need to embed the VLC player in an Angular component so that it is displayed on the web, but I can't do it.

I have searched this website for all the related questions but I have not found the answers or perhaps I have not known how to implement them since I am still a junior in programming.

Possible data to take into account: Camera:
-Tapo C500
-Angular: 17.0.9
-VLC Media Player: 3.0.20

Among other ways, I have tried the following:

- VLC component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vlc-player
- git example: https://gist.github.com/mpgn/4229a08ffdc69e7a4e28
- git example: https://github.com/tuxity/angular-vlc

Thanks so much for your time and effort.

Comment: ActiveX is dead - so you can't embed VLC (or any other media-player) into a web-page anymore. That "VLC Component" npm link you pasted does not do what you think it does: it's just an (awful) wrapper over NodeJS's `spawn` to open `vlc.exe` on Windows. You can't use it in a web-browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Dai . I'm looking for other alternatives, do you know anything that might work today?

Comment: You can play RTSP directly in the browser now: https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Dai . I will chew this information to see what it gives me. A greeting and thank you very much again

Comment: ops, I'm seeing that this is a paid solution. It's not an option for me. I need the solution to be open source.
Thank you very much anyway for your willingness to help.

Comment: It is an open-source project, it's Apache-licensed. The stuff advertised on Streamedian's website are for value-added services on-top, such as their own hosted streaming media server - you don't need that because you said you already have an RTSP stream you want to display, so I can't see anything that would stop you from using this with your own RTSP source.